# How to shutdown a program after x amount of time without input

Tags: java

I am writing a program in java where after x amount of time without any input from the user, it does shutdown like System.exit(0). Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Start a timer...

Comment: bad way of asking question in here like that. [Guideline how to properly ask in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?

Comment: please post your real scene or make more specific what are you want to do. You can make a triger to call like System.exit(0) depanding on some kind of conditions

Comment: Please elaborate the scenario more clearly. And Show us the code you attempted.
In my understanding, you want to close the application after a certain time of inactivity was met.

Why not use timer and check if user has been inactive for a while
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_timer.htm

Comment: *"Does anyone know how can I do this?"* Yes. Did that answer help you at all? If not, then maybe you should learn to ask better questions. Perhaps you should read some of the good articles in the [**Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help), e.g. "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 0):

Use a Timer class and add a timer schedule task into it which will act like an exit process. Once timer up, exit the program.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final long thresholdTime = 11 * 1000;//in seconds
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Game Over. Couldn't cancel the time bomb.... Booommm.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }, thresholdTime);

        // Normall processing of program...
        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        // When you think you are good with your inputs.. call this
        timer.cancel();

    }
```